# XSLT sort order to match order of different parent node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two nodes that incidentally share a subset of their data. I need to sort the first set based on the original order of the second.

To give an example, consider the following sets of points and lines. Every "start" and "end" point for each line will in every case also be listed in the Points list.

```
<Points>
    <Point name="Point1">0 0</Point>
    <Point name="Point2">0 1</Point>
    <Point name="Point3">1 1</Point>
    <Point name="Point4">1 0</Point>
</Points>

<Shape>
    <Line name="Line1">
        <Start>0 0</Start>
        <End>0 1</End>
    </Line>
    <Line name="Line2">
        <Start>0 1</Start>
        <End>1 1</End>
    </Line>
    <Line name="Line3">
        <Start>1 1</Start>
        <End>1 0</End>
    </Line>
    <Line name="Line4">
        <Start>1 0</Start>
        <End>0 0</End>
    </Line>
</Shape>
```

I need to sort Points so that the values match the same order as the End points listed for the Shape.

For the above example, the expected XSLT output would be as follows...

```
Point2 0 1
Point3 1 1
Point4 1 0
Point1 0 0
```

To be specific, I'm working with COGO Points and Alignment objects from AutoCAD, trying to customize reports based on LandXML outputs from Civil3D. The sample above is just to give me some direction. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Comment: XSLT version 1.0. I'm using Autodesk LandXML Reporting 8.0 to process the files.

Comment: What if there are more Ends than Points?

Comment: Because of how the XML files are being generated, there will always be the same number of points as ends. I'm selecting an alignment from my drawing that was created by the points. The problem is that the points aren't recorded in the same order in the XML file, unless they are specifically selected in the drawing as such, which isn't always convenient to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work: a template that matches `End` nodes and grabs the `Point` node with the same text value (there's a second template matching all `text()` to make sure it doesn't get outputted unintentionally):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/root/Shape/Line/End">
        <xsl:variable name="endPtText" select="./text()" />
        <xsl:value-of select="/root/Points/Point[text() = $endPtText]/@name" /><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$endPtText"/> <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:transform>
```

Produces:

```
Point2 0 1
Point3 1 1
Point4 1 0
Point1 0 0
```

from:

```
<root>
  <Points>
    <Point name="Point1">0 0</Point>
    <Point name="Point2">0 1</Point>
    <Point name="Point3">1 1</Point>
    <Point name="Point4">1 0</Point>
  </Points>

  <Shape>
    <Line name="Line1">
        <Start>0 0</Start>
        <End>0 1</End>
    </Line>
    <Line name="Line2">
        <Start>0 1</Start>
        <End>1 1</End>
    </Line>
    <Line name="Line3">
        <Start>1 1</Start>
        <End>1 0</End>
    </Line>
    <Line name="Line4">
        <Start>1 0</Start>
        <End>0 0</End>
    </Line>
  </Shape>
</root>
```

[XSLTransform](http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiJS)

Just note that if you have two identical `Point` text nodes this won't work, and if you don't have a `Point` node corresponding to an `End` node this won't work.

Comment: No prob, but as I mentioned in the post be aware that if you have two `Point` nodes with the same text value it may give you unintended results

Comment: Point input requires that they are unique, so that should be of no concern. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

> there will always be the same number of points as ends.

In such case, the problem could be restated as:

> List all the end points in document order, along with the
>   corresponding point name.

And the best technique to achieve this would be to use a **[key](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** - for example (simplified to illustrate the principle):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="pt" match="Point" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Shape/Line">
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('pt', End)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Point name="Point2">0 1</Point>
  <Point name="Point3">1 1</Point>
  <Point name="Point4">1 0</Point>
  <Point name="Point1">0 0</Point>
</root>
```

Comment: Ahh yes, key is much more elegant than my solution.